# Java Generics of the form <T extends A<T>> and Inheritance

Tags: java, generics

I have a tricky problem with Java generics, or maybe I can't see the wood for the trees.

I have three classes, A, B, and C that look as follows.

```
abstract class A<T extends A<T>> {
    abstract T sefl();
};

abstract class B<T extends B<T>> extends A<T> {
};

class C extends B<C> {
    @Override
    C sefl() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Later I have different versions of B's as well as different versions of C's. Furthermore, I have a function test that should accept a list of B's (or of one of its cousins). Or in general, it should accept any list of elements that inherit from A. Unfortunately, I need to know the type of the list's elements in the function's body, i.e. the uppermost type a.self can return (or the type T). Function test looks as follows:

```
static <T extends A<T>> void test(List<T> list) {

    for (A<T> a : list) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        T t = a.sefl();
    }

}
```

Now, calling test with a list of C's works.

```
List<C> cs = new LinkedList<C>();
test(cs);
```

But

```
List<B> bs = new LinkedList<B>();
test(bs);
```

results in a warning requiring a type parameter and

```
List<B<?>> bs = new LinkedList<B<?>>();
test(bs);
```

is not valid. Where is my mistake, or how can I create a list of B's that is accepted by function test?

---

Some words to the motivation behind this problem. The classes A, B, and C (or Animal, Mammal, and Cat) implement a tree-like data structure, where each class extends the structure with some properties. Typically, all super-classes are abstract and you can only create instances from leaf-classes, e.g. cat. Now, the difficulty is that the classes implement a copy-on-write policy (COW), i.e. modifying an object creates and returns a new instance of itself with the modified property.

For example, let’s say all animals have an age property. You can easily define this property in Animal, and you can provide a getter method to return the age.

```
abstract class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> {
    private int age;
    public int getAge(int age) {
        return age;
    }
};
```

However, how do you define the setter method? You can write it as follows:

```
public abstract Animal setAge();
```

This requires that (at least) each non-abstract element must implement the setter function. For example:

```
class Cat extends Mammal<C> {

    @Override
    public Animal setAge(int age) {
        return new Cat(/* .. */);
    }
}
```

Remember, as we implement a COW policy, we must create a new instance. So, in the setter function (e.g. implement in Cat) we return a new cat with the new age. Calling cat.setAge(4) on a Cat element returns a new Cat. Unfortunately, because of the type signature, we only now that we got an Animal returned from setAge, even if we call it on a Cat directly. The twist with the generics helps to reveal the concrete type when calling setAge. So, we can construct Animal like this:

```
abstract class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> {
    private int age;
    public int getAge(int age) {
        return age;
    }
    public abstract T setAge();
};
```

And in Cat we can say:

```
class Cat extends Mammal<C> {

    @Override
    public Cat setAge(int age) {
        return new Cat(/* .. */);
    }
}
```

---

So, back to the problem. Your right, using `List<? extends Animal<?>>` as the type of the list works, but unfortunately, I need some way to know the type of the elements. Or more concrete: Function test must replace the old element with the new one. For example:

```
static void test2(List<? extends Animal<?>> list) {
    for (Animal<?> animal : list) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Animal<?> a = animal.setAge(4711);
        list.add(a);
    }
}
```

And unfortunately, the list extension list.add(a); ist the statement that doesn't work with this signature.

Comment: Btw: after changing the type of B to: abstract class B<T extends B<T>> extends A<B<T>> {}; function test accepts list of the form List<B<?>> bs;, but obisouly function test does no loger accepts lists of C's ala List<C> cs;.

Comment: Dont put more information into comments. Not only because getting them to "format" right requires some knowledge. Always update your question instead of putting more info into shattered comments.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this? You can invoke `test(new LinkedList<>())`, but that's probably not much use.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualising what A, B and C might be, or under what situations you'd want to enforce these constraints. Can you provide a better example? (no `DefaultAbstractConfigurationManagerFactory`s though ;) )

Comment: This is a very simplified example. In practice, I need to modify the element (which returns a copy of itself) and I need to replace the old element with the new one in the list.

Comment: What's wrong with `List<B<C>>` ?

Comment: Object doesn't extend B, so B<?> is broken, you could try B<? extends B>.

Comment: @matt `? extends B` should automatically be inferred...but that's not the error anyway

Comment: @MarkoPacak why would ? extends B be inferred? Also they claim that List<B<?>> is not valid. So I don't get your statement about the error. Anyways, I offered them as suggestions to the op.

Comment: No you can't add items to a `List<T extends ...>`; this wasn't part of the initial problem though. Also please notify me when you make some edits. Your updates might as well be comments in my answer...I'll look for solutions then I'll come back. If you have any more requirement you should write them ASAP

Answer (score 4):

Well, they are two very different implementations:

```
class C ...
```

and

```
class B<T extends B<T>> ...
```

The class `C` doesn't declare any generic type.

---

Simple letters for class names are a bit confusing here, so let's do:

```
abstract class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> {
    abstract T sefl();
};

abstract class Mammal<T extends Mammal<T>> extends Animal<T> {
};

class Cat extends Mammal<Cat> {
    @Override
    Cat sefl() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

---

So:

```
List<Cat> catList = new LinkedList<>();
```

works well, as there is no generic type involved. The compiler determines that

```
Cat extends Mammal<Cat> ( == Cat extends Animal<Cat> )
```

fits within the bounds `<T extends Animal<T>>`

On the other hand for

```
List<Mammal> mammalList = new LinkedList<>();
test(mammalList); // ok, but mammal list of what???
```

the compiler can't match the bounded types.

In fact, `Mammal<T extends Mammal<T>> extends Animal<T>` doesn't have anything to do with `<T extends Animal<T>>`.

Even by providing a wildcard, you'll never be able to pass a `List<Mammal<?>` to `test`. The method signature rejects it!

---

**A possible solution:**

A more generic test method

```
static void test2(List<? extends Animal<?>> list) {
    for (Animal<?> animal : list) {
        Animal a = animal.sefl();
    }
}
```

can be used along with different `List` types:

```
List<? extends Mammal<?>> bs = new LinkedList<>();
test2(bs);

List<Cat> catList = new LinkedList<>();
test2(catList);

List<Animal<Cat>> animalList = new LinkedList<>();
test2(animalList);
```

---

Java version:

```
java 9.0.4
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Can't we write test2 as `static <T extends Animal<?>> void test2(List<T> list){
        for(Animal<?> a : list) {
        //code
        }
    }` ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. To execute the statement 'list.add(a);' we must know that the element is of type T.

Comment: @slemoine yes you can, yours is a correct usage as well. Keep in mind that, as I wrote, mine is **a** possible solution

Comment: @slemoine ok you can't. I just saw the question updates

Comment: @MarkoPacak nor do I ;). I was still sticking with your first answer for the original question. Thanks